# Sharing desktops in Ubuntu desktop 22.04

Tags: desktop-sharing

I noticed that compared to 18.04 remote sharing of desktops has changed in 22.04.

It has been improved to support connecting from MS Windows to Ubuntu using MS Remote Desktop software. I suppose that was the idea.

From perspective of connecting from Ubuntu to Ubuntu it does not seem like an improvement however. In fact it basically now no longer works.

VNC is now a "legacy" protocol so I suppose it should not be used. It also does not work anymore. I cannot connect using Remmina on Ubuntu 18.04 to a Ubuntu 22.04 machine.

A RDP connection sort of works. With scaling "on" it shows half the screen so it sort of works but it is not usable.

When using Ubuntu 22.04 what is the best way to share desktops? Is there some documentation on how this can be done?

When I disable VNC can I use TightVNC for example?

Comment: Today I stumbled upon the very same issue: can't connect from an Ubuntu computer to an other Ubuntu computer. My desktop PC is using Ubuntu 22.04. It could connect to the remote computer when it was using Ubuntu 20.04. After upgrading this to 22.04 does it not work any longer. Have you meanwhile found a solution?